# A fast(er) way to find something that matches a pattern in the list

Tags: java

Given a unordered list of `List<String>`, I need to find whether there exist a `String` that matches supplied String.

So, i loop

```
    for (String k : keys) {
        if (Utils.keysMatch(k, anotherKey)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Where `Utils.keysMatch` checks if appropriate matching can happen.

**Can the same be done without a complete iteration?** Note that `k` may be a regular expression.

Comment: Is this list exceptionally large?

Comment: @Bill About 2-2.5 million keys

Comment: Could you provide some context for the problem.  For what you described there is pretty much no faster way.  But if you describe the problem there may be a better data structure.

Comment: Will you search the List only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in elegant way with Guava's [Iterables.any](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#line.619) method and static Predicates class

like this:

`return Iterables.any(keys, Predicates.containsPattern(k);`

Answer (score 1):

No. In the worst case, the very last element you look at is the first that matches, so you have to look at them all.

Of course, if you could precompute a suitable data structure, you might achieve faster results.